# How to retrieve a process cmdline after setproctitle?

Tags: linux, process

I tried looking at how sshd spawns its processes and caught something like `sshd: [priv]` in the process list. When I tried reading `/proc/pid/cmdline` I got the `sshd: [priv]` name but I was wondering how to retrieve the original command line?

I know that in the sshd case I can simply look at the sources, but is there a way from just using what the system provides?